# Set Camera Input Frame resolution in zxing barcodescanner android librery

Tags: zxing

i am design a android Application that use Zxing librery for read and decode Qr code , but my problem My problem is this

1- input frame resolution is so big for proccess

for sample i can change frame resolution from 1980/1024 to 680/420 e.g

my using librery is 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'

thank you